# Retrieve multiple values from table, bit value and ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to retrieve all data related to a spesific ID and also all of those data that have a bit value of 1 within the same table.

This is the table data:

```
Description
--------------------- 
INT        DID
INT        DescID             
VARCH      DescTitle
VARCH      DescText
BIT        ForAll

Description_Join
---------------------
INT        DJID
INT        DescID
INT        ProductID
```

The tables are joined by the DescID. So now I would like to show all data with a specific ProductID (from request.querystring) and i will also like to display ALL data from the table "description" where the field "ForAll" has the BIT value of 1.

I just cannot get this to work.

This is the Sql I have tried

```
SELECT D.DescID, DJ.DescID, DJ.ProductID, D.ForAll, D.DescTitle, D.DescText 
FROM Brand_Variant_Description D
INNER JOIN Description_Join DJ ON (D.DescID = DJ.DescID)
WHERE DJ.ProductID=222 AND D.BrandDescAllSel=1
```

Comment: writing error in the last line. Should be ... `AND D.ForAll=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you need all data that matches specific productid plus data with bit value 1 even if it has different productid. if this is what you need, then in your query change Inner join as Left join and replace final AND as OR like this

```
SELECT D.DescID, DJ.DescID, DJ.ProductID, D.ForAll, D.DescTitle, D.DescText 
FROM Brand_Variant_Description D
LEFT JOIN Description_Join DJ ON (D.DescID = DJ.DescID)
WHERE DJ.ProductID=222 OR D.BrandDescAllSel=1
```

Comment: In think the inner join should remain an inner join and not a left join though. And the BrandDescAllSel is of course be ForAll.

Comment: Excellent, that was just what i was looking for! Thanks @Jasqlg

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query

```
SELECT D.DescID
    ,DJ.DescID
    ,DJ.ProductID
    ,D.ForAll
    ,D.DescTitle
    ,D.DescText
FROM Brand_Variant_Description D
LEFT JOIN Description_Join DJ ON (D.DescID = DJ.DescID)
    AND (D.ForAll = 1)
WHERE DJ.ProductID = 222
    AND D.BrandDescAllSel = 1
```